# Raspberry pi OS is 32bit?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, software-recommendation

I haven't used the Raspberry Pi website in a while, and I want to download and install the Raspberry Pi OS to an SD card, to boot my Raspberry Pi 3b+. The website keeps telling me the OS is 32 bit. I thought the Raspberry Pi 3b+ was 64 bit. I don't want to use a 32 bit OS if my hardware is 64 bit. I'm finding the new website very confusing. I know how to clone image files in Linux, that's no problem, it's just the semantics of the website, and even finding the proper download. Did Raspberry Pi move away from 64 bit OS support?

Comment: If you don't want to use a 32-bit system on a 64-bit CPU don't.  No one will force you to.  Many of us (several millions?) are quite happy to do so.

Answer (score 4):

The raspberry OS (Raspbian) is 32 bits, the 64bits version with the 64bits user land is in beta right now.

If you need 64 bits kernel with userland you will need other OS, like Ubuntu, Gentoo or Arc.

The thing with stick with Raspian are the updates.